# Homebrew Export Settings

Tags: macos, import, export, homebrew, homebrew-cask

Looking for a way to export my homebrew and homebrew cask installations (everything from 'brew list' and 'brew cask list')

I'd like to be able to export them to a file that I can then put on any new machine, and run some sort of install that will install them automatically.

Basically using something like a package.json for package management.

Comment: The way your question is formatted at the moment doesn't fit with stack overflow rules and will likely attract a large number of down votes or be closed very quickly. To avoid this, it's a good idea to edit your question to provide clear examples of your overall problem, what issues you're facing, what you have tried, and why those don't work. Also, it's worth searching to see if your question has already been asked before.

Answer (score 6):

This is exactly what [homebrew-bundle](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-bundle) does.